# Editing MP3 tags

Tags: java, android, tags, jaudiotagger, mp3agic

Does anyone of you know a way to edit the tags of an mp3 file?
I tried Mp3agic but it crash when I try to declare an *MP3File* object and I also tried tha jaudiotagger library, but it also crashes.

I need help please.

UPDATE:

This is the code snippet where the app crash:

```
     File testFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/Music/test.mp3");
        TagOptionSingleton.getInstance().setAndroid(true);

        AudioFile audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(testFile);

        Tag newTag = audioFile.getTag();
        newTag.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM, this.album);
        newTag.setField(FieldKey.ARTIST,this.artist);

        audioFile.commit();
```

The app crash at the line

```
AudioFile audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(testFile);
```

without exception.

By following all debug steps from the aforementioned line, the app crash at line 246 of the MP3File class of JAudioTagger.
This is the lines:

```
..
finally {
        if(newFile != null) {
            newFile.close();
        }
```

### ..

So I tried to change my code here (I changed the AudioFile declaration):

```
File testFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/Music/test.mp3");
        TagOptionSingleton.getInstance().setAndroid(true);

        AudioFile audioFile = new AudioFile();
        audioFile.setFile(testFile);

        Tag newTag = audioFile.getTag();
        newTag.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM, this.album);
        newTag.setField(FieldKey.ARTIST,this.artist);

        audioFile.commit();
```

And at line

```
AudioFile audioFile = new AudioFile();
```

it throw a NullPointerException at line 232 of MP3File class (the line tries to find the header of the file):

```
audioFile: Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFile.toString()
```

This exception cause in the next lines this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void org.jaudiotagger.tag.Tag.setField(org.jaudiotagger.tag.FieldKey, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

At line:

```
newTag.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM, this.album);
```

UPDATE:

I tried also to change the line:

```
Tag newTag = audioFile.getTag();
```

To:

```
Tag newTag = audioFile.getTagOrCreateAndSetDefault();
```

But it throw this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create default tag for this file format
```

Comment: The problem is that..it crash without excpetion, I used the debug to follow every step...but there's no exception threw

Comment: I am also using a Try Catch but no exception is thrown and nothing appears in Logcat,it crashes without exceptions or messages

Comment: You are being downvoted (not by me) because you should really provide more information, and preferably some code to show how you are trying to do this :)